# How does the dataflow authenticate the worker service account?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I created a service account in project A to use as a worker service account for dataflow.
I specify the worker service account in dataflow's options
I've looked for an dataflow's option to specify Service account keys for the worker service account, but can't find it.

I ran it with the following program arguments and it worked fine.I ran it with a service account that is different from the worker service account that exists in project A.

```
--project=projectA --serviceAccount=my-service-account-name@projectA.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

I didn't load the Json credentials file for the worker service account in my Apache Beam application.
And I haven't specified the service account key for the worker service account in the dataflow options.

How does the dataflow authenticate the worker service account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [Dataflow security and permissions -> Security and permissions for pipelines on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#permissions).

It uses the project's Compute Engine default service account as the worker service account by default.

Comment: Thanks for the input.I understand the role.
I used to be able to specify a service account key file (setServiceAccountKeyFile) in dataflow's options, but that option is no longer available.
I would like to know how the worker service account specified in the dataflow options is authenticated without specifying a service account key.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. I am not exactly familiar with the internals, but there is a metadata server provided by GCE that provides credentials for the Compute default service account. Take a look at [GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/8239b89fe11bd4043433b659c0a070275e3fc82b/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.java#L96)